# Error casting servlet: "main" to javax.servlet.Servlet

Tags: java, spring, servlets, struts, weblogic

Please suggest me to resoleve the error.In my project using struts,spring.I am getting this error when running the apps.

```
<Error> <HTTP> <BEA-101126> <[ServletContext(id=15938176,name=efund,context-    path=/efund)] Error casting servlet: "main" to javax.servlet.Servlet
java.lang.ClassCastException
at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:134)
     <BEA-101216> <Servlet: "action" failed to preload on startup in Web  application: "efund".
javax.servlet.ServletException
```

Please let me know , what is the problem in my project ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: post code.......................

Answer (score 4):

Looks pretty straightforward to me. The class `com.thetravel.ld.tools.efund.servlets.HIMain` is registered as a servlet called "main", but it doesn't implement `javax.servlet.Servlet` (i.e. it isn't a servlet).

Answer (score 3):

Either `HIMain` doesn't extend `GenericServlet` or `HttpServlet`, **or** your application is including its own copy of the Servlet API. The latter can cause classloading problems like this one.

Make sure you don't have `servlet-api.jar` (or something like it) in your application.